# I want to use sprintf to pull out a string from NSString instead of using UTF8String?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to use sprintf to pull out a string from NSString instead of using UTF8String?
I know this works:

```
NSString *nsSDummy = [[NSString alloc] initWithObjects: @"red"];
char *strDummy;

strDummy = [nsSDummy UTF8String];
```

But want to do the following:

```
NSString *nsSDummy = [[NSString alloc] initWithObjects: @"red"];
char *strDummy;

sprintf(strDummy, "%@", nsSDummy); <<--Unknown conversion type character "@" in format
```

thanks

Comment: sprintf is a C function and is not aware of the existence of NSString and the meaning of %@. What's wrong with UTF8String anyway?

Comment: With the sprintf I could have include more than 1 item... simplifies

Comment: with formats you can include more than one item as well... `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@",@"a",@"big",@"dog"];` will be the string `@"a big dog"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can't be done that way, as sprintf dosn't know anything about Cocoa data types.

you can use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat`, or `NSMutableString`'s `appendFormat:` method
then use that constructed string to create the cString, i.e.

```
NSString *nsSDummy = @"red";
NSString *derivedString = [NSString stringWithFormat: "%@",nsSDummy];
char *strDummy = [derivedString UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

In the case you posted, there is no reason to use `sprintf`. Just use `UTF8String` and be done with it. In a more complicated case, use NSString's `stringWithFormat:` method and then use `UTF8String` on the resulting NSString.

I hope it's just a result of trimming for the post, but you're using `sprintf` completely incorrectly (you're passing it an uninitialized pointer) and will wind up with a crash or worse. And you really should use `snprintf` or `asprintf` instead anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You must alloc strDummy or do this way

```
int len = 10;
char[len] _strDummy;
char *strDummy = &_strDummy;
//...and continue your code
```

Good look!